# Spring Kafka Request Reply Partition pattern: Unable to commit offset after processing message

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am implementing Synchronous Request Reply pattern with Spring Kafka.
Stack:

org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.2

org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka

io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:6.2.0

Java 11

---

I have a request topic with 5 partitions and response with 8 partitions

My Response consumer side configuration is as follows. I have not shown producer config for brevity:

```
  @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, PhmsPatientSearchRequest, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, PhmsPatientSearchRequest> pf,
                                                                                                                 KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> container) {
        final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, PhmsPatientSearchRequest, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> repl = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        repl.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return repl;
    }

 @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> replyConsumerFactory) {
        TopicPartitionOffset topicPartitionOffset = new TopicPartitionOffset(replyTopic, replyPartition);
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topicPartitionOffset);
        final KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> msgListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(replyConsumerFactory, containerProperties);
        return msgListenerContainer;
    }

 @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> replyConsumerFactory() {
        final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
        return consumerFactory;
    }

 @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "ResponseConsumer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 40000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, replyDeserializerTrustedPkg);
        props.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL, schemRegistryUrl);
        props.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER, true);
        return props;
    }
```

My request reply code is

```
  ProducerRecord<String, PhmsPatientSearchRequest> patientSearchRequestRecord = new ProducerRecord(requestTopic, phmsPatientSearchRequest);
        // set reply topic in header
       
        patientSearchRequestRecord.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, messageKey.getBytes()));
        //patientSearchRequestRecord.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, replyTopic.getBytes()));
        //patientSearchRequestRecord.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION, intToBytesBigEndian(replyPartition)));
       
        // post in kafka topic
        RequestReplyFuture<String, PhmsPatientSearchRequest, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> sendAndReceive = replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(patientSearchRequestRecord);

        // get consumer record

        ConsumerRecord<String, PhmsPatientSearchResponse> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();
```

I receive my response message on the correct partion but the offset is not committed.
Following stacktrace is observed every time my response consumer reads the message. I do not think this is due to some poll delay.

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.handle(RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1606) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1256) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1163) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1173) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1148) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:206) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:169) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:129) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:602) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:412) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1005) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1495) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2656) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2651) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2637) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2451) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1235) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

If I do not use TopicPartitionOffset, then my consumer listens to all partitions in response topic and has no problem.

Requesting help on this matter.

Comment: Since you are manually assigning the partitions (which is correct); you should not be seeing rebalancing messages since group management is not being used.
Something very odd is going on - perhaps you have some other consumer with the same group name that is using group management?

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for responding. I have commented out the manual assignment and still faced the same issue. Also, I am running the kafka, the replier and the requester app in local only. And running just one requester app. I got same issue.

Comment: @GaryRussell Once I added following configuration the consumer config on the requester app, then the issue stopped happening.   props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest"); I am hoping to understand what is this configuration doing that addresses this issue.

Comment: One more thing which I tried was to use enable auto commit. Then I kept getting the error message frequently, even without sending any message. Is there any way, we can connect once @GaryRussell or I can share my entire poc code with you ?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code (but using `String`s), and it works as expected...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68461640Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68461640Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so68461640").partitions(5).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic reply() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so68461640.replies").partitions(8).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
        final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> repl = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(
                pf, container);
//      repl.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return repl;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer replyContainer(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> replyConsumerFactory) {

        TopicPartitionOffset topicPartitionOffset = new TopicPartitionOffset("so68461640.replies", 3);
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topicPartitionOffset);
        final KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> msgListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(
                replyConsumerFactory, containerProperties);
        return msgListenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> replyConsumerFactory() {
        final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerConfigs());
        return consumerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "ResponseConsumer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 40000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,  "earliest");
        return props;
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "so68461640", topics = "so68461640")
    @SendTo
    public String listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> replyTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyKafkaTemplate,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> replyTemplate,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {

        factory.setReplyTemplate(replyTemplate);

        return args -> {
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future =
                    replyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord("so68461640", 0, null, "test"));
            future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            ConsumerRecord<String, String> reply = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(reply.value());
        };
    }

}
```

```
test
TEST
```

```
% kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group ResponseConsumer

Consumer group 'ResponseConsumer' has no active members.

GROUP            TOPIC              PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
ResponseConsumer so68461640.replies 3          1               1               0               -               -               -
```