# ReplyingKafkaTemplate with KafkaReplyTimeoutException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

been butting heads for a while with this issue.
I am trying to achieve that my Kafka setup allows me to retrieve an answer after a Kafka record gets consumed.

So I have a producer and a consumer. The consumer should process the Kafka message and then publish a response in a centralised reply topic which the producer then handles.

I have read a lot of different implementations of the ReplyingKafkaTemplate, but trying to go with the simplest, and with least configuration route, available in the Spring Kafka documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template

Here is my current code (let me know if you need any more info).

**Producer:**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> replyingKafkaTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory, final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
        final ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = consumerFactory.createContainer("replies");
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); // unique
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest"); // so the new group doesn't get old replies
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setKafkaConsumerProperties(props);
        final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> requestReplyKafkaTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, kafkaMessageListenerContainer);
        requestReplyKafkaTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(true);
        return requestReplyKafkaTemplate;
    }
}
```

In my controller:

```
private final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> kafkaTemplate;

@GetMapping
@ApiOperation("Get list of all entities")
public ResponseEntity<List<model.response.EntityDTO>> listEntities() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    final ProducerRecord<String, Object> listEntitiesProducer = new ProducerRecord<>("main-topic", kafka.events.AllEntitiesQuery.builder().build());

    return Optional.ofNullable(
                        kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(listEntitiesProducer).get().value())
                .map(entitiesList -> ResponseEntity.ok(entityMapper.mapToDTOs(Lists.newArrayList((EntityVO[]) entitiesList))))
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
}
```

As you can see, I am also following the part of the documentation where I have a shared topic for replies, hence the unique group ID.

**Consumer:**

Has no custom Kafka configuration.
Listener:

```
@KafkaHandler
@SendTo
public EntityVO[] queryAllEntity(final AllEntitiesQuery allEntitiesQuery, @Headers final Map<String, String> header) {
    return entitiesMapper.mapEntitiesList(entityRepository.findAll()).toArray(new EntityVO[]{});
}
```

The consumer handler gets triggered; I can debug into it and check the content of the headers:

[image: headers content on consumption]

The receivedTopic matches "main-topic", the replyTopic matches "replies" (when converting the bytes).

So it seems the problem is that the consumer is not able to publish the reply back to the replies topic. The original producer then times out waiting for a reply:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.KafkaReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:119)
    at com.controller.EntityControllerKafka.listEntities(EntityControllerKafka.java:90)
    at com.controller.EntityControllerKafka$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e8204732.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.ControllerInterceptor.aroundGetMapping(ControllerInterceptor.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
```

I can also confirm, by monitoring topic traffic, that no messages are written to the replies topic. I have tried multiple configurations on the consumer, to no avail (also the documentation doesn't indicate anything needed and I just assume the consumer uses the KafkaTemplate bean with the properties it gets on the headers).

Out of ideas and appreciate any input!

Comment: There might be some error on the consumer side. Also if you can debug that `queryAllEntity()` why just don't follow in debug session down to the reply producing logic in `spring-kafka`? It feels more like it cannot serialize that your `EntityVO[]`...

Comment: I have debugged a bit further... as far as I can understand it reaches setupReplyTo in spring kafka's DelegatingInvocableHandler.java, but it can't resolve a replyTo unless I specify manually the topic name in the sendTo annotation. If I do specify the topic name manually it seems to work fine, but the headers on the listen also contain the replyTo topic name, so I assume that should work?

Comment: I assume too, but can’t debug Kafka 3.0 on my Windows to give you more info

Comment: What version are you using? Does it work with `@KafkaListener` on the method instead of the class? I just changed my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68461640/spring-kafka-request-reply-partition-pattern-unable-to-commit-offset-after-proc) to use a `@KafkaHandler` method and it works fine.

Comment: I ended up replicating what is done in this guide: https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2018/10/26/synchronous-request-reply-over-kafka/ and specifying, manually, the sendTo reply topic.
I am using version 2.5.4 of Apache Kafka (letting Spring Boot determine the best version here). I will try the @KafkaListener on the method.

Comment: KafkaListener on the method level works without specifying the reply topic name in SendTo.